# How to read a csv file into a list of lists in SWI prolog where the inner list represents each line of the CSV?

Tags: csv, io, prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

I have a CSV file that look something like below: i.e. not in Prolog format

```
james,facebook,intel,samsung
rebecca,intel,samsung,facebook
Ian,samsung,facebook,intel
```

I am trying to write a Prolog predicate that reads the file and returns a list that looks like

```
[[james,facebook,intel,samsung],[rebecca,intel,samsung,facebook],[Ian,samsung,facebook,intel]]
```

to be used further in other predicates.

I am still a beginner and have found some good information from SO and modified them to see if I can get it but I`m stuck because I only generate a list that looks like this

```
[[(james,facebook,intel,samsung)],[(rebecca,intel,samsung,facebook)],[(Ian,samsung,facebook,intel)]]
```

which means when I call the head of the inner lists I get `(james,facebook,intel,samsung)` and not `james`.

Here is the code being used `:-` (seen on SO and modified)

```
stream_representations(Input,Lines) :-
    read_line_to_codes(Input,Line),
    (   Line == end_of_file 
    ->  Lines = []
    ;   atom_codes(FinalLine, Line), 
        term_to_atom(LineTerm,FinalLine), 
        Lines = [[LineTerm] | FurtherLines],
        stream_representations(Input,FurtherLines) 
    ).
```

```
main(Lines) :- 
    open('file.txt', read, Input), 
    stream_representations(Input, Lines), 
    close(Input).
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with `term_to_atom(LineTerm,FinalLine)`.

First we read a line of the CSV file into a list of character codes in
[`read_line_to_codes(Input,Line)`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_codes/2).

Let's simulate input with [`atom_codes/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_codes/2):

```
?- atom_codes('james,facebook,intel,samsung',Line).
Line = [106, 97, 109, 101, 115, 44, 102, 97, 99|...].
```

Then we recompose the original atom read in into `FinalLine` (this seems wasteful, there must be a way to hoover up a line into an atom directly)

```
?- atom_codes('james,facebook,intel,samsung',Line), 
   atom_codes(FinalLine, Line). 

Line = [106, 97, 109, 101, 115, 44, 102, 97, 99|...],
FinalLine = 'james,facebook,intel,samsung'.
```

The we try to map this atom in `FinalLine` into a term, `LineTerm`, using [`term_to_atom/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_to_atom/2)

```
?- atom_codes('james,facebook,intel,samsung',Line), 
   atom_codes(FinalLine, Line),
   term_to_atom(LineTerm,FinalLine).

Line = [106, 97, 109, 101, 115, 44, 102, 97, 99|...],
FinalLine = 'james,facebook,intel,samsung',
LineTerm =  (james, facebook, intel, samsung).
```

You see the problem here: `LineTerm` is not quite a list, but a nested term using the functor `,` to separate elements:

```
?- atom_codes('james,facebook,intel,samsung',Line), 
   atom_codes(FinalLine, Line),
   term_to_atom(LineTerm,FinalLine),
   write_canonical(LineTerm).

','(james,','(facebook,','(intel,samsung)))

Line = [106, 97, 109, 101, 115, 44, 102, 97, 99|...],
FinalLine = 'james,facebook,intel,samsung',
LineTerm =  (james, facebook, intel, samsung).
```

This `','(james,','(facebook,','(intel,samsung)))` term will thus also be in the final result, just written differently: `(james,facebook,intel,samsung)` and packed into a list:
`[(james,facebook,intel,samsung)]`

You do not want this term, you want a list. You could use [`atomic_list_concat/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/2) to create a new atom that can be read as a list:

```
?- atom_codes('james,facebook,intel,samsung',Line), 
   atom_codes(FinalLine, Line),
   atomic_list_concat(['[',FinalLine,']'],ListyAtom),
   term_to_atom(LineTerm,ListyAtom),
   LineTerm = [V1,V2,V3,V4].

Line = [106, 97, 109, 101, 115, 44, 102, 97, 99|...],
FinalLine = 'james,facebook,intel,samsung',
ListyAtom = '[james,facebook,intel,samsung]',
LineTerm = [james, facebook, intel, samsung],
V1 = james,
V2 = facebook,
V3 = intel,
V4 = samsung.
```

But that's rather barbaric.

We must do this whole processing in fewer steps:

1. Read a line of comma-separated strings on input.
2. Transform this into a list of either atoms or strings directly.

DCGs seem like the correct solution. Maybe someone can add a two-liner.

Comment: Incidentally, it seems that text processing in Prolog is done heavily with "atoms" (which are not really used atomiccy but as pieces of text) rather than "strings" (which in SWI Prolog are a special datatype, but are traditionally lists of character codes, i.e. integers). I would rather use strings...